# When is $on loaded needed in an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following [this angular tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/dVRdu6dXNT/8-adding-comments-and-voting-to-our-application#item-53045c7d605b1e5d77000039) and am confused by the $on("loaded", ...) calls.

```
$scope.user.$on("loaded", function() {
  populatePosts();
  populatecomments();
});
...
function populatecomments() {
  $scope.comments = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.user.comments, function(comment) {
    var post = Post.find(comment.postId);
    post.$on("loaded", function() {
      $scope.comments[comment.id] = post.$child("comments").$child(comment.id);
      $scope.commentedPosts[comment.postId] = post;
    });
  });
}
```

Why can't we just call populatePosts() and populatComments() here? Why is a second $on("loaded", ...) needed within populatecomments() if it isn't called until loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first:

```
$scope.user.$on("loaded",...
```

will be triggered when $scope.user is loaded, the second:

```
post.$on("loaded",...
```

will be triggered for each post when the given one is loaded.

Angular(and mostly javascript) does network calls asynchronously, so if you want to postprocess their result, you have to define a callback which will be called when they are loaded.

As you see `populatecomments()` uses `$scope.user.comments` which could be inaccessible if you call `populatecomments()` directly, outside of the loaded event handler.

Comment: So it's like an AJAX call? How do you know when on loaded is needed?

Comment: Yes. If you tries to do anything with the returning data you should do it when it is loaded. => You have to encapsulate the post process logic to the success promise call or the loaded event's handler.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's not. You could (and should) refactor this code to use [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) instead.

Comment: What would this code look like when refactored in this way? Any other links you can provide about promises?

Comment: The entire way everything is designed would have to change. Every function that fired an event would instead return a promise object, and every subscriber to the event would instead chain a method to the resolution via `.then()`. Here's a tutorial on promises from html5rocks: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/. It talks about ES6 promises, but has links to polyfills and full blown libraries that you can use today.